# Show error on using preprocessor before the main function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 1
#if A
printf("Csau");
#endif
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to run this but my compiler is giving me the error of

> main.c:4:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before
>
> string constant   printf("Csau");

Any suggestions why this isn't working ?

P.S. In main function it's working fine with some minor modification.

Edit : Anyway I can show the output outside the main function ?

Comment: You can't run code outside of a function.

Comment: It's not the preprocessor that's wrong, you're calling a function before the main function.

Comment: can I use "#" before printf ?

Comment: _can I use "#" before printf ?_: you can use preprocessor commands (the stuff that starts with #, like #define, #if, #endif etc. anywhere.

Comment: @Vivank No.  You can't just put `#` before anything.  There are only a few things the preprocessor can do, and printf isn't one of them.  You can do `#error`, though.  That is, if you want to halt compilation, with an error message, if the wrong preprocessor macros are/aren't defined, you can do that with `#error`.

Comment: Check the edit pls

Comment: Are you trying to print this thing at the time the program is being compiled, or at the time it runs?

Comment: @Vivank What do you mean by "show the output outside the main function"?  If you put the `printf` call inside of the `main` fucntion, it will get printed more or less first thing after the program starts running.  But as I understand it you don't want to put the `printf` call there.  But what do you want the `printf` call to do differently?  Why do you want to put it outside of `main`?

Comment: When it runs @SteveSummit

Comment: @Vivank Okay.  If you put the `printf` call inside of `main`, the string will get printed when the program runs.

Comment: Just curiosity @SteveSummit sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can output messages at compile time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A 1
#if A
#warning "Csau"
#endif
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

At runtime you can not print something outside another function body.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you are trying to call printf from outside of main (or outside of another function)

**Edit : Anyway I can show the output outside the main function ?**

No.  The program starts at the beginning of the "main" function.  Putting code outside of functions is syntactically incorrect.  Even if the compiler let you do it, the code would never be executed.

Comment: Anyway so that I can use printf function outside the function ?

Comment: No, but you can call it from inside of main.  You can also use the #if A inside of main as well.

Comment: The important thing to remember is that the computer starts the program at the beginning of main.

Answer (score 2):

Once preprocessed, your code boils down more or less to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

printf("Csau");

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And this is not correct C. You cannot call a function outside functions. It doesn't make sense. When you run the program, the system calls your `main` function and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor doesn't run before `main()` (aka: before execution) but **before compilation**. The actual compilation step is fed the results of preprocessing as input, so, in your case, an *invalid C program*, as you can't have statements outside of functions.

At runtime of your program, there **is nothing before entering `main()`**. Of course, your runtime will probably setup a few things, but anything happening before `main()` is called is *not part of your C program*.